# Swift: Make large title start small or big everytime

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am currently working on a projekt in swift where I use a navigation controller to segue between different views. My projekts title is displayed in the navigation bar after the segue with "prefer large titles" on and it displays automatic. It all works as it should, but for some reason the title is not displayed the same way after the segue at the different views. When I segue to a viewcontroller with a scrollview the title is displayed like this to begin with

> [image]

And when I segue to a tableviewcontroller the title is displayed like this

> [image]

Do you know why it is displayed differently? I do not care how the title is displayed to begin with, just that it is in the same way every time. You can see the problem in this link

https://github.com/Rawchris/small-title

Comment: Check the functionality on the mainStoryboard. Seems like the navigation bar "prefer Large title" is activated.

Comment: @AkhileshSharma Yes, that is actually also the point. I want the large title, but it displays differently after the segue. This is not a problem when you start scrolling because the title will automatically adapt

Comment: Can you provide a video or gif of the behavior that is happening? That will be a little more helpful than the words or the image provided.

Comment: @AkhileshSharma Yes, give me two seconds

Comment: As what i can see as the behavior, if i get that right this happens when you have a second transition ??

Comment: @AkhileshSharma Hmm... I am not sure that is the case. It seems like a general problem

Comment: @AkhileshSharma I have uploaded a link to a project where you can see the problem

Comment: Ok. Let me check

Comment: Please check that the scrollview top is constraint to viewcontroller top and not safearea top

Comment: Let me know if that works! And would appreciate if the answer satisfies your need, mark the answer accepted to close the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to your problem.. Thanks for sharing the repo.

This declaration is from your ViewController. In addition to this, as you are adding the components programmatically so i would suggest to mark `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to be `false`

```
lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let view = UIScrollView(frame: .zero)
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.minX, y: CGFloat(0.0), width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height)
        view.contentSize = contentViewSize
        return view
    }()
```